# Why is the connection considered insecure on the catch-all server when using https?

Tags: nginx

I set up a catch-all server in a separate conf file. My goal with this is to create a global configuration so that it is not necessary to define a default_server on each virtual host. However, even using a valid certificate, the connection is still considered insecure. Why does it happen? Is this normal when code 444 is returned?

sites-available/rejected.conf file:

```
server {
    listen       80  default_server;
    listen       443 ssl default_server;
    server_name  _;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.key;
    return       444;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that server block is used? You could add a seperate access_log for this server and see fi your access is logged

Comment: What you mean with *“a valid certificate, it is still considered invalid”*

Comment: Please show the hostname defined in `certificate.crt` and the exact request you made when testing this.

Comment: The certificate is a wildcard. It would be something like `* .myplace.mydomain.com`. When I access servername.myplace.mydomain.com or even the server's ip in the browser, I don't expect anything to be returned. I just want names linked to virtual hosts to return something in the browser. @HermanB I changed my question.

Comment: Maybe my explanation got bad. The connection is considered insecure when the name linked to the server or ip is accessed through a browser. The virtual hots configured in other conf files are accessed via https without problems. For example, when accessing `myapp.myplace.mydomain.com`, the connection is shown as valid. Does access via ip or server name make the connection insecure due to return code 444? I am curious about this. I don't know if it would affect anything in production.

Comment: Access log for `servername.myplace.mydomain.com`. I removed only the ip from the log. `[29/Mar/2021:16:00:41 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 444 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments of the original post, you're encountering the issue when you access myplace.mydomain.com or the IP address of the server. You also state that you're using a wildcard certificate of *.myplace.mydomain.com. If it doesn't have a SAN for myplace.mydomain.com, it wouldn't match, and therefore is invalid; likewise, because SSL uses hostnames and not IPs, it will not match on the IP address and will be invalid there also.

Check what SANs your cert covers like this:

`openssl s_client -connect myapp.myplace.mydomain.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep DNS:`

You should get something back like this:

```
                DNS:*.myplace.mydomain.com, DNS:myplace.mydomain.com
```

You'll note here that the two entries cover any subdomain of myplace.mydomain.com (`*.myplace.mydomain.com`), as well as the regular domain itself (`myplace.mydomain.com`). If you only have the wildcard for the subdomains, you'll not match the certificate when someone goes to myplace.mydomain.com.

Comment: When accessing `servername.myplace.mydomain.com` or your `IP`, the request automatically goes to the default catch-all server. I really want this to happen.

 Due to return code 444, nothing is accessed via the browser. I just want to know why the connection is described as insecure in these cases, although I manage to see the ssl certificate as valid. I imagine it is because no page linked to a virtual host has been loaded. I am right ? Would this bring any problems?

Comment: My answers tells you reasons it may be considered invalid.

Comment: The command `openssl s_client -connect myapp.myplace.mydomain.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep DNS:` returns an error: `unable to load certificate
140366260634752:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE`

Comment: How did you put your certificate on your machine? Did you copy it from a Windows machine or something? Basically it's saying that the cert is failing validation.

Comment: I did not copy from a Windows machine. In the browser the certificate is shown valid for `myapp.myplace.mydomain.com`. My key is certificate.key and not certificate.pem.